# How to get data from Collection Map in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, discord, discord.js

For my bot in discord, I would like a !help command that loops through all commands, gets the name, and returns them in a message back to the user. I have created **fs** to loop through my /commands/ folder:

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.extraCommands.set(command.name, command);
}

console.log(client.extraCommands);
```

Returns a Collection Map that looks like: (cropped for sake of simplicity)

```
Collection [Map] {
  'args-info' => {
    name: 'args-info',
    execute: [Function: execute]
  },
  'channel-info' => {
    name: 'channel-info',
    execute: [Function: execute]
  }
```

All I need is to store the `name` of each command into an array.

I've tried looping through to get the key but that doesn't seem to work...

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If it's a `Map`, you can loop through `for(const key of client.extraCommands.keys()){/* Add key to an array */}` or just use `client.extraCommands.keys()` since it's an iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, at first, I thought I should make a loop to go through all files and get the 'name' attribute. However, the `.keys()` returns an array for all properties inside the map 
[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Comment: I never said you need to loop yourself to get the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the key names are your command names, so this should do the trick.

```js
let keys = Array.from(client.extraCommands.keys());
```

Answer (score 0):

Both lines of codes will return the same result as you want.

```
[...client.extraCommands.keys()] //using map keys
[...client.extraCommands.values()].map(({name})=> name); // using key 'name' from each map value
```